# How to install Visual Studio Code's `code` command permanently?

Tags: macos

I just followed the top-voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx) and successfully installed Visual Studio Code's `code` command in my terminal.

However, the `code` command fails to launch Visual Studio Code every time after I restart my MacBook Pro.

```
~ code
zsh: command not found: code
```

Is it possible to install `code` permanently so that I don't have to install it every time I turn on my MacBook Pro?

```
~ where code
/usr/local/bin/code

~ ls -l /usr/local/bin/code
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myName  admin  167 Aug  5 13:41 /usr/local/bin/code -> /private/var/folders/bh/525lnbns1213cx2651s97my00000gp/T/AppTranslocation/EA379FC4-05D2-4739-BE49-1D8870E47B8A/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

I also find out that the folder `EA379FC4-05D2-4739-BE49-1D8870E47B8A` get deleted after I restart my laptop.

This is the reason that I cannot run `code` after the laptop is restarted.

Why is `code` installed in a temporary folder?

My MacBook Pro's version is *macOS Sierra version 10.12.6*

Comment: Simplest solution i found is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604469/5650332

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Looks like your whole Visual Studio got installed in a temporary folder.

- Remove the current link with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/code`
- Start Visual Studio from within `/Applications`
- Reinstall `code` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971430:

  > Now open the Command Palette (F1 or ⇧⌘P on Mac) and type `shell command` to find the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` command.

If it still doesn't work you can also link manually by running

```
sudo ln -fs "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution works. I found that my `Visual Studio Code.app` was in `Downloads` folder. The `code` command is installed in `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`
after I dragged it to `Applications` folder.

Comment: Moving VSCode from `/Downloads` to `/Applications` and re-running the VSCode pallette command did the trick for me too.

Comment: The manual link worked for me, thank you!

Comment: running `SHELL Command: Uninstall 'code' command in PATH` then running `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 9):

If you're on Mac OS Catalina, you need to edit your **`.zprofile`** instead of `.bash_profile`.

1. Edit your *~/.zprofile* file: `vim ~/.zprofile`
2. Add the following code in it, on it's own line: `code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}`
3. Save the file: `:wq`
4. Re-run the updated file: `source ~/.zprofile`.
5. Test that running `code .` opens your current folder in VS Code!

Answer (score 4):

OK, it seems "ln" command not work for me (I use this command set up sublime text). But I got an another solution.

1. edit your ~/.bash_profile file.
2. add the following code in it.
   `code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}`
3. after save. do not forget to run `source ~/.bash_profile`.
4. Finished and test it, type `code`

Comment: For zsh, we probably want to edit `.zshrc` instead of `.bash_profile`, though. That way, we don't need to `source ~/.bash_profile` each time we need the settings...

Answer (score 4):

**GOOD TO KNOW:**
Since Catalina update, MacOS uses zsh bash environment by default*
*[Resource about zsh and terminal](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050)

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:**
Personnal settup: currently using macOS with Catalina:

- bash file & location: **.zshrc**, **~/.zshrc**
- .zshrc existance: `ls -la`  >
  and **look for .zshrc** file

  - if no .zshrc file: `touch .zshrc`
- **open & write** –– `alias code="open -a 'Visual Studio Code'"`.
  *Which will behave like what Monomeeth mentioned above:

  opens your VSCode from your folder Applications.*

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed was that my `Visual Studio Code.app` was in `Downloads/`, not `Applications/`.

If this is the case, run `mv /Users/<your-user-name>/Downloads/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app /Applications` and try again!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

simple solution if you recently reinstalled VS Code and don't want to *sudo*: Just drag & drop Visual Studio Code.app from Downloads to Applications.

then run `.code` in whatever terminal you use on mac